# Are these Big-O notations correct for simple modulus and power functions (Python)?

Tags: python, function, big-o

Suppose we have the following functions:

```
def modulo(a, b):
    """Take numbers a and b and compute a % b."""
    if b <= 0:
        return None
    div = int(a / b)
    return a - div*b

def power(a, b):
    """Take number a and non-negative integer b.
    Compute a**b."""
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return a * power(a, b - 1)
```

For `modulo`, is the big-O notation `O(a / b)`? Because the time it takes to execute depends on  a and b inputs. However, I've seen modulus computations online where the big-O notation is `O(logn)`, so not sure if that's applicable here. Can anyone clarify?

For `power`, would the big-O notation be `O(a^b)` because it involves powers?

Comment: For the modulo you dont have a loop. You are executing only 1 thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Following the previous answered question***

Time complexity is calculated for repetitive tasks. Therefore, if you don't have loops in general, you don't talk about time complexity. You are just applying one thing.

So for `modulo` you can 'ignore it' `(O(c)) c is a constant`.

For the `recursive function`, since we are re-entering in the function each time, until `b==0`,  then the complexity is `O(b)` similar to `O(n)` from the previous question. (`linear`)

If you google `Recursion` it will show you `did you mean recursion` and if you keep clicking it, it keeps taking you to the same page, therefore, recursion is a repetitive task. That is why it you consider it similar to a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`modulo` has no loop, it just does constant time operations (math), so it's O(1). `power` will decrease `b` by 1 until it's `0`, and the rest of the function is O(1), so it's O(1*b) or O(b).